# How to do row-wise comparison between SQL (Oracle) fields?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, compare

Take the following table as an example:

```
-------------------------
| time      | start_time|
-------------------------
|  50       | 80        |
|  20       | 72        |
|  45       | 30        |
-------------------------
```

I would like a query which returns all rows where `time` is less than the `start_time` given in the corresponding row, this query should return:

```
-------------------------
| time      | start_time|
-------------------------
|  50       | 80        |
|  20       | 72        |
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from tablename
where time < start_time
```

You can try this assuming both the columns are numeric.

Comment: thanks. How would the operator `<` behave if `time` and `start_time` did not have the same number of rows?

Comment: @Alex.. i am not sure i got what you are saying? `time and start_time did not have the same number of rows?`

Comment: i am just curious about the bahaviour of the `<` operator. So if the RHS is a scalar it compares all rows with the scalar, and if the RHS is a column with the same number of rows as the LHS, it does row-wise comparison, as per your answer and my example. But, what happens if the number of entries on either side do not match?

Comment: it would only be either of the cases as you are mentioning. I can't right now, think of a case where the number of entries on either side wouldn't match.

Comment: For example if the second side was obtained using a subquery.

Comment: it would be equivalent to a row-wise comparison. for each value from a row on the LHS it would compare the RHS based on the conditions specified.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86841/discussion-between-alex-and-vkp).

Comment: ok, thanks to the helpful discussion I have worked out that you cannot do a row wise comparison (or in fact, any comparison) if the RHS is given by a subquery returning more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want compare scalar with set. You can use "any" or "all" keyword. But i'm not sure that you have asked about it. [ALL, ANY and SOME Comparison Conditions in SQL](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql)

```
select * from temp_table where 
time < any (select start_time from temp_table)

select * from temp_table where 
time < all (select start_time from temp_table)
```

Comment: not what I asked, but this is useful to know thanks.